# HP LaserJet 1010 driver for OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, drivers, printer, osx-lion, hp-laserjet

I've been looking for a website where I can find the software of HP LaserJet 1010 driver for OS X 10.7. I found a source in the official website of HP but I couldn't find the download button or link

http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=306507&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D%257CswItem%253Dlj_96574_1%257CswEnvOID%253D4114%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken

Can someone help me and find out where I can find the download button in that page? or if you have other sources where I can find the software, please provide it to me

Comment: Unless I can't read, it says `Use Apple Software Update to obtain the latest HP driver update for OS X 10.7 (Lion). For more information, go to Products supported in OS X 10.7 (Lion) (c02950970) (in English) `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl907), ish. The trick (lately) has been getting Apple software update to start bothering to get the HP drivers - once it's got them it seems to update them, but it's utterly stupid about going and getting them the first time for the past several months, at least.

The link is to an apple knowledgebase article that includes an Hp Printer Software download for 10.6-10.9 which will hopefully jumpstart the process successfully.

I know I've had issues with HP 4000's (which I have drivers installed for on 10.7 computers) coming back as "no driver available" when installed on 10.7 systems that didn't already have the HP drivers onboard this past year. I tracked down that KB article in hopes of sorting it out, but most of my affected users have left, and were getting by on the "generic post-script" driver. Previously the printer install process would kick a software update to grab the drivers, and it would find them - lately the "no driver available" claim has been coming back, despite the fact that systems with the drivers are pulling updates to them just fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Description section on the page you linked, you should "use Apple Software Update to obtain the latest HP driver update."  Have you tried that?